# Django 'object is not iterable' error when using get() method

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

get() method is not working in Django,

I have a model BlogPost, when I try to fetch data from that model using get() method it shows

Error :
'BlogPost' object is not iterable

```
def blog_post_detail(request, slug):
    query = BlogPost.objects.get(slug=slug)
    template_name = 'blog/post.html'
    context = {'query': query}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

But the same thing works using filter() method

```
def blog_post_detail(request, slug):
    query = BlogPost.objects.filter(slug=slug)
    template_name = 'blog/post.html'
    context = {'query': query,}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Note: I have only one post in BlogPost

Comment: Probably you may be trying to iterate `BlogPost` object in the detail view.

Comment: Well, `get` returns a single instance, `filter` returns a queryset which is an iterable over instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `.get()` on a queryset will return a single instance of that model. There's a for loop in Your template iterating over the instance.

Comment: Thank You for helping

Answer (score 0):

The error is not happening during the `.get()` operation. It's being caused when you're passing the `context` in the template. Pretty sure the code in your template is iterating over your `context.query` and showing the BlogPost object.

Answer (score 0):

just don't iterate in the template('don't use loops instead pass query.name or whatever is inside your modal ')

1. first check whether the problem is really in `get()`.method :

   ```
   def blog_post_detail(request, slug):
       query = BlogPost.objects.get(slug=slug)
       print(query)
       return HttpResponse(query)
   ```

Before using this make sure you used

```
 def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

in your model  and import HttpResponse

if this returns Httpresponse or printed data then Don't use  for loop in your template